# Where to put sounds in MVC Java game?

Tags: java, audio, design-patterns, model-view-controller, layer

I'm working on Java app using **MVC design pattern** and now I want to play some sounds. Where should I put audio sounds for playing using code? To which layer of `MVC`?

Some of the sounds should be played after a user pressed some key so it would be fine to include it in Controller. However some sounds are played just after some time and without user interaction where just Model knows about this change. But putting sounds in Model sounds to me like a bad idea so... How can it be solved?

Comment: You mean sound files themselves? Or logic that controls sound play?

Comment: logic, code itself :)

Answer (score 1):

Sound Play is something standing aside from MVC pattern.

It has some similarities with View from MVC since it also provides some information to a user. But it is simpler. Sound module can't consume user input so it doesn't require Controller.

I'd recommend you to **implement the sound module applying [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)**. Your Model generates events and Sound module subscribes to those events. It will be subscribed in exactly the same way as the View module.

Let me give you an example. Let's say you have a player that shuts a gun.
Internally your model will generate say `ShutGunEvent`. Both View and Sound will be subscribed to this event. View will draw flying bullet and Sound will play gunshot sound.

Comment: Interesting idea, thank you. But how should I notify one specific observer? Because now I'm notifying views from model using `this.notifyObservers()`. I want to notify view whenever model is changed but I want to notify sound module just in some cases.

Comment: Yo mean you notify all view objects at once on every change in the model? It is better to organize your model objects the way that their changes influence only on specific part of the view. That way every model object will have different set of observers. In such model your sound observers will be treated exactly the same way. EG. In case of gun shot you need to change only bullet and gun view. You don't need the rerender the menu line so menu view should not receive any events.